# Is $(3^p-1)/2$ always squarefree?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I have little conjecture. Maybe it's stupid i don't know.

Let $p>5$ be a prime number. Then $(3^p-1)/2$ is always squarefree?

It's true for $p<192$.(I used Mathematica.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is even unknown for the usual Mersenne numbers $M_p=2^p-1$. All such numbers, where the factorisation is known, are squarefree. However, Guy (1994) believes that there are $M_p$ which are not squarefree. As far as I know, a similar conjecture holds for $N_p=3^p-1$ and $N_p/2$.

Answer (score 5):

If $q^2$ divides $3^p-1$ with an odd prime $p$ , then $q$ must be a Wieferich-prime to base $3$. The only known Wieferich-primes to base $3$
are $11$ and $1006003$ (https://oeis.org/A014127). There is no other example below about $10^{15}$.

The example $11^2|3^5-1$ was ruled out by your condition $p>5$. There is no prime $p>5$ with $11^2|3^p-1$ because the order of $3$ modulo $11^2$ is $5$.

The order of $3$ modulo $1006003^2$ is $1006002$. Since this is not prime, $3^p-1$ cannot be divisible by $1006003^2$.

So, $3^p-1$ is almost certain squarefree for $p>5$.

Answer (score 0):

This is true if and only if there exist a prime $q$ such that $p \mid q-1$ and $3$ is a $q(q-1) /p$ residue modulo $q^2$. There are $p$ of them, uniformly distributed among the $q(q-1) $ coprimes with $q$. For a fixed $q$, this happens with probability

$$A(q) := \sum_{p \mid q-1} \frac{p}{q(q-1) } $$

And one can see that the probability of finding a counterexample up to $x$ is

$$ P_x := 1- \exp \left (- \sum_{q \le x } A(q) \right )  $$

If the sum of contributions  $\sum_q A(q) $ diverges, then $P_x \to 1$ as $x$ goes to infinity and we are almost sure that a counterexample exists. However, it seems to me that $A(q) $ can be bounded from above on average by something like $\log(q) ^4 /q(q-1) $ which converges, and this would be very bad :( in practice, it would mean that if you substitute $3$ with say $5$, the probability is the same and we don't know in advance for which bases we hit such a counterexample.

I suggest you try to compute the sum $\sum_q A(q) $ and see if this converges or not; little is known about the sum of primes dividing a number, and it maybe the case that for numbers of the form $q-1$ this is bigger than on average.

**Edit**. Note also that the characterization at the beginning could be used to approach the problem in a direct way. There exist a version of quadratic reciprocity law for higher residues using the [Hilbert Symbol](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_symbol), and since it is easy to understand if $q^2$ is a $q(q-1) /p$ residue modulo 3, one has some hopes to understand if $3 $ is a residue modulo $q^2$. Unluckily, I am not an expert, and I don't know how difficult it is to compute the other term (the generalization of the sign $(-1) ^{\frac{(p-1)(q-1)}{4}}$ to higher powers).

Comment: Andrea - I don't understand your introductory sentence. If I translate it into Pari/GP I get the following, but not $3$: `[p=5,q=11]; (q*(q-1)/p) % (q^2)` giving the answer `22` where, if I understand your sentence correctly I expect $3$ instead of $22$. What did I get wrong?

Comment: Let's see if I got some number wrong. Let $g$ be a generator mod $q^2$ and suppose $g^k = 3 \pmod{q^2}$. The équation $3^p = 1 \pmod{q^2}$ is équivalent to $kp = 0 \pmod{q(q-1) }$. If $p \nmid q(q-1) $ we get $k=0 \pmod{q(q-1) }$, that is $3 = g^0 = 1 \pmod{q^2}$, which is impossible. Otherwise the équation reduces to $k=0 \pmod{q(q-1) /p}$. Setting $k = s \cdot q(q-1) /p$ we get $3= g^k = (g^s) ^{q(q-1) /p} $ which shows that 3 is a $q(q-1) /p$ power. On the other hand if $3= y^{q(q-1) /p}$, by generalized fermat little theorem we get $3^p= y^{q(q-1) } =1$.

Comment: I think I got your misunderstanding; sorry for the general answer but I didn't got your point at the beginning. By " $x$ being an $n$ residue modulo $q^2$" I mean that exist $y$ such that $y^n = x \pmod{q^2}$!

Comment: Andrea- ah thank you for your comment. This *modulo* sentences are very often a nightmare for me... (only topped by something like "order of multiplicative cyclic groups" or "multiplicative order of cyclic groups" and/or including the term "modulo..." ... ;-( )