# $\frac{q^p-1}{q-1}$ squarefree?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, mersenne-numbers

Is $\frac{q^p-1}{q-1}$ always squarefree with $q,p$ prime and $p>2$ and $(q,p)=(3,5)$ excluded?

This is a follow up of [$3^p-2^p$ squarefree?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3154578/3p-2p-squarefree)

I know the case $q=2$ (Mersenne) and $q=3$ are still open, but is there a similar/generalised conjecture for the other prime $q$?

Comment: A prime number $r$ with the property $$r^2\mid \frac{q^p-1}{q-1}$$ must be a Wieferich-prime to base $q$, that is $$q^{r-1}\equiv 1\mod r^2$$ must hold.

Comment: Yes, necessary, but not sufficient

Comment: I am not actually sure whether it is even necessary, but if $r$ does not divide $q-1$, then surely.

Comment: can't we apply the same reasoning as for the mersenne case? If $r\mid \frac{q^p-1}{q-1}$, than $p$ is the smallest exponent for which $r\mid \frac{q^p-1}{q-1}$. Since I look only at $p>2$, $r\nmid (q-1)$

Comment: For Mersenne numbers $\ r\mid q-1\ $ is impossible because of $\ q=2\ $, so in this special case we actually have the necessary condition. Since the known Wieferich primes (to base $2$) can be ruled out and another Wieferich prime (to base $2$) must be huge, we can conclude that $2^p-1$ with prime $p$ is always squarefree with a high probability.

Comment: Hi Collag3n - I've explored that question in an attempt on a generalized approach. See the index http://go.helms-net.de/math/index.htm and entry on "high Fermatquotients". If the introducing remarks are interesting to you you might like to read http://go.helms-net.de/math/expdioph/fermatquotients.pdf as well. The occurence of such generalized Wieferich primes is very sparse, but to detect more structure in the problem, I extended the mechanism to composite numbers (calling this then perhaps "Euler-quotients") to collect more data and get hints towards hidden mechanics in the problem...

Comment: For the term "wieferich prime" it is sufficient when $w^2 | (q^p -1)/(q-1) $ with $p=w-1$ (or a divisor of $w-1$); it is ***not needed*** that $p$ is also ***prime*** to give $w$ the attribute "Wieferich-prime" (to base $q$). The question ***here*** introduces one more restriction: in that  $p$ must as well be prime. So the Wieferich-primes $w_1=1093$ and $w_2=3511$ do not match the question as stated. This is different when $w=11$ and $w^2 | (3^5-1)/(3-1)$ because $p=5$ is as well prime, this case fits the requirements of this question.

Comment: @Gottfried Helms, thanks. You made some good point, I think I should put this back on top of my ToDo list :)

Answer (score 3):

The following PARI/GP-code finds examples :

```
? forprime(q=2,100,forprime(p=3,30,if(issquarefree((q^p-1)/(q-1))==0,print([q,p]
))))
[3, 5]
[53, 23]
[53, 29]
[67, 3]
[71, 23]
[79, 3]
?
```

So, for example $$\frac{53^{23}-1}{53-1}$$ is not squarfree.

Comment: Arff...indeed. was too concentrated on higher $p$ than higher $q$. I wonder if there are any pattern in the $q$ for which it would still be true

Comment: @Collag3n and Peter: the additional restriction of $q \lt p$ makes the problem really difficult...

Answer (score 2):

You can construct counterexamples easily enough.  For instance, say we want an example divisible by $29^2$.  Noting that $\varphi(29^2)$ is divisible by $7$ we first find an element of order $7$ $\pmod {29^2}$, I got $645$ with a little calculating.  Then we find a prime $q\equiv 645 \pmod {29^2}$, I think $22511$ is the least.  Then we get $$\frac {22511^7-1}{22511-1}\equiv 0 \pmod {29^2}$$